# How can I add a table in each iteration of my loop?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am generating a word document from excel using VBA. I have a for loop that I would like to add a [1 row, 1 column, bordered] table to. This is an area where the user can put their comments inside a word document. When I try to add .table.add I have been getting different errors ranging from object errors. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub GenDocumentables()
    Worksheets("checklist").Activate
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Dim saveName As String
    Dim NumberOfCells As Integer
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        'Debug.Print .Version
        .Documents.Add
        With .Selection
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .BoldRun
            .Font.Size = 13
            .TypeText "Documentable Items for "
            .TypeText Range("d4").Value
            .BoldRun
            .TypeParagraph
        End With
        NumberOfCells = Range("a4", Range("a3").End(xlDown)).Count
        For loopcounter = 1 To 2 ' NumberOfCells
            With .Selection
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Style = wdStyleHeading3
                .TypeText Range("a3").Offset(loopcounter, 0).Value & " - "
                .TypeText Range("a3").Offset(loopcounter, 4).Value
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .TypeText Range("a3").Offset(loopcounter, 5).Value
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Italic = True
                .TypeText "<<Please enter your commentary here. Ensure all aspects of the check content are met>>"
                .TypeParagraph
                '-------------------ADD TABLE HERE-------------------
            End With
        Next
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=myRange, UseFields:=False, UseHeadingStyles:=True, LowerHeadingLevel:=3, UpperHeadingLevel:=1
        With .Selection
            .GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        End With
        saveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\My Word Doc_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".docx"
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 saveName
        '.ActiveDocument.Close
        '.Quit
    End With
    MsgBox "done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because a selection can't add a table?

Comment: yeah, that didn't help.

Comment: What did you try in place of select? Edit: you have been here long enough to know SO isn't a code service.

Comment: I tried recording a macro to get code and plug it in:

Comment: ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
                1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
                wdAutoFitFixed
            With Selection.Tables(1)
                If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
                    .Style = "Table Grid"
                End If
Did not work

Comment: Sigh. That's the downside of recording macros. Users rarely go back to study what it means. One learns far better by writing code from scratch XD Well, macros can't record a `for loop`. So you do know something. Please look into what `with` statements do.

Comment: Please add code to OP not comments. Make it readable.

Comment: Don't see where you added the new lines XD Are you doing it within or outside the loop?

Comment: I can't even decipher what's selected XD Also, did you increment your loop? Guess 1 to 2 needs no increment?

Comment: The loop goes from 1 to 2 so that I don't print 351 lines in the word doc - only two. I tried to add the activedocument code above just outside the .selection "end with" in the loop to no avail.

Comment: I am not as familiar with word so I don't know what methods and properties it holds. Where you're putting it means it's qualified to `.Documents.Add` (a new word doc) if I follow correctly which one would think would hold a method for adding a table but you might want to doublecheck. It's still unclear to me what the selection inside the loop pertains to :/ I don't think it's the excel book as you believe... Basically, qualify your objects.

Comment: Duh. If you can record a macro that reads `ActiveDocument.Tables.Add ` of course it holds that method XD `Range:=Selection` Might want to replace selection with something concrete.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  I will look into this and post the solution once I have determined what that is.

Comment: Sure. Seems JDB clarified most of my comments. Not sure if I agree with the select given that that defeats the purpose of setting objects but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting object errors due to the fact that Selection does not have a method .Table
To get around this, you'll want to use the line:

```
Set newTable = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(SomeRange,1,1)
```

Tables is a member of Document, which you can retrieve using the section wdApp.ActiveDocument. 
Here, SomeRange needs to be defined for this to work properly.

To try and get this code running, lets try and add a few variables to make this easier.
Back where you declare your other variables add these:

```
Dim myRange As Word.Range
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim newTable As Word.Table
```

and before you enter your loop, AFTER you create the document add:

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
```

Next, inside of your loop, but after your End With (.Selection) you could add:

```
Set myRange = wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Content.End - 1, wdDoc.Content.End)
Set newTable = wdDoc.Tables.Add(myRange, 1, 1)
newTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Hello"
Set myRange = wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Content.End - 1, wdDoc.Content.End)
myRange.Select
```

Let's go through what this does.

- First, it sets out custom variable myRange to be the last character in the document. This allows us to place the Table underneath everything that's already been created,
- Next, it creates a table at this location, with the size 1x1.
- The value of the first cell in this table is set to "Hello"
- The next line then AGAIN sets the range to the bottom of the file, then selects it. This is neccessary because creating a table changes the selection to be inside of the new table. Skipping this line would have you then run the next iteration of the loop INSIDE of the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly. You made my day.
Thank you for the VERY clear explanation. Especially "Tables is a member of Document" `Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument`